# Searching music by melody - is it offtopic here?

Tags: discussion, search

I have a problem in finding (recognizing) an artist/title of a specific melody which I'm able to reproduce. I have tried Google Play Sound Search and SoundHound (midomi.com) - both returned irrelevant results after I passed a midi playback to them. I suppose only human audience could recognize the melody.

The question: is it legitimate to ask such questions here and if not, does StackExchange provides another site where it's possible? The task is basically: find music by example. Existing automatic services work great if a fragment of exact audio (with all arrangement) is passed to them, but make a blunder if only a main theme draft is specified.

Comment: this might help.. I found it from another answer on Music.SE. You can search for melodies by entering notes on a keyboard/staff, or you can just give the overall contour (up, down, up, up, etc). You can also whistle or sing it into a microphone I believe. Not sure about accuracy, but it's probably worth a try:

http://www.musipedia.org/

Comment: Thank you for asking before posting! I'm sorry we can't be more help to you this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is off topic on this Stack Exchange site - we have a specific close reason:

**Questions on identifying (or finding) a particular song, genre, instrument, etc. are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers.**

There is a new proposal - [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) - which may have this within scope, however I think it still needs about 100 more people to sign up.

I'm not sure what other solutions you have - you are correct in thinking SoundHound requires the original track, as it takes samples of the audio at numerous points - it doesn't just check the melody notes.